# Convert it into Data and time format for different time zones

Tags: java, angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-scope

while selecting a date from the datepicker in the jsp page coming format as like this.

while logging  in from India the datepicker format is as follows:

```
String datestr = "Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)";
```

while loging  in from the US the datepicker format is like as follows.

```
String datestr1 = "Tue Dec 31 2013 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)";
```

I want to convert it into both 'dd-MMM-yyyy' format.

suppose in future i want to login in from other countries i.e internalization the same format output it will come.

Now we are implementing in the angularJS (jsp page) application .

sample javacode is as follows which is working fine for India but not working for US.

How can i make it possible to work for all countries?

How can i implement generic function in javacode supports all formats.

```
public class CurrencyConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Date date;
        String convDate = null;
        String datestr = "Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)";

        String datestr1 = "Tue Dec 31 2013 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)";
        try {

            datestr =  datestr.replace("+"," ");
            date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").parse(datestr1);
            convDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(date);
            System.out.println(convDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            }

        }
```

Comment: why you need to accept a date string rather than a numeric time-stamp value?

Comment: Accempting timestamps on the server is vastly better as then the locale conversation is already taken care of for you.